# What is "Amaury"?

Tags: traducción, letras

I see a book by Alexandre Dumas named "Amaury" in Spanish?

What is the English equivalent? Or is it simply the same (I'd never heard of it, if so).

It is available here:  http://www.booksshouldbefree.com/book/Amaury-by-Alexandre-Dumas

Comment: As some answers have said, it's just a male name. *Amaury* is a novel by Dumas, published in 1843. You can see it listed in the French or Spanish versions of the Wikipedia article on Dumas. It doesn't appear in the English version, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a French first name from old Gothic origin (**Amalric**). It has many variations including **Aymeric** (French), **Amalrich** (German), **Imre** (Hungarian), **Emery** and **Emerson** (English), **Américo/Emérico** (Spanish) and  **Amerigho/Amerigo** (Italian) from which the **Americas** take their name (Americo Vespucci).

Answer (score 5):

It is a person's name.
There is a famous singer called Amaury Perez

Comment: En Cuba el no es muy popular que digamos ;)

Comment: ¿Y eso?, ¿por qué?

Comment: En cuba el no le cae muy bien a la gente, un poco engreido y guatacon del gobierno, la mama de el consuelo vidal si era muy popular

Answer (score 1):

Amaury is just a person's name. According to a quick search on google its origin is German and French.

Acording to [Babynamesworld](http://babynamesworld.parentsconnect.com/meaning_of_Amaury.html)

Combination of the german 'amal' meaning "work, bravery" plus 'rik' meaning "power, ruler."
Brought to England by the Normans. This is a given name which evolved into a surname and in modern times, appears as both. This is the French form.

Amaury may also be from 'helm' meaning "helmet" and 'rik' meaning "ruler."

The english equivalent is the same `Amaury`

Answer (score 1):

The title of this book in English is also Amaury.

[Here](http://www.cadytech.com/dumas/work.php?key=11) you can find two reviews of the book in English.

From the first review, I can tell Amaury de Leoville is the main character in this book.

In the second review, you can find a list of English translations:

- "Amaury," New York, Harper, 1845, pp. 106. Tr. By E.P.
- "Amaury," London, Methuen, 1904, sewed, pp. 132. Another edition, with coloured plates by Gordon Browne. 1904. Reprinted, same firm, 18mo., 1921, pp. 317. In the reprint the introduction is wrongly ascribed to "R.S.G.".
- "Amaury," London, Collins Bros., pp. 319, 1930.

Answer (score -1):

Es un nombre muy popular en América Latina

Comment: Das ist ganz ulkig/merkwuerdig; so ein Name! Es lautet ulkig, es sieht ulkig aus...ach!

Comment: zum Beispiel the guy from Prision Break :P  http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1004774/

Comment: Ich sehe kein Fernsehen an, also weiss ich nichts darueber. Mit so einem Namen wuerde ich so einen einfach "Ami" nennen.

Comment: Denkst Du Brunhilde klingt viel schöner?xD.Jeder Sprache hat hässlichen Vornamen...

Comment: This might be technically correct, but it needs more information to be a good answer. Can you explain who he is? Perhaps a link to his biography on Wikipedia or elsewhere would be beneficial. It also doesn't answer what the equivalent title is in English.